# Refresh div on button click Jquery (Transforming code from automatic to on button click)

Tags: php, jquery, html

How to make it so that this code will be activated (without the automatic timer ofcourse) on the click of a button and refresh a div that has been set.

So for instance with this button:

```
<a id="refresh">Refresh</a>
```

This code works, but automaticly refreshes every second.

```
<script>
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function()
        {
        $('#load_new').load('class_admin_search.php?logfile=<?php echo $_GET['logfile']; ?>&search=<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>');
        }, 1000);
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#load_new').load('class_admin_search.php?logfile=<?php echo $_GET['logfile']; ?>&search=<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>')
        })
    </script>
```

I couldn't find any code which was working, this is the closest which I could find, the rest doesn't work.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code. you dont need to use setInterval function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on('click','#refresh',function(){
      $('#load_new').load('class_admin_search.php?logfile=<?php echo $_GET['logfile']; ?>&search=<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>')

   }); 

 });
```